# merging two observables before saving knockout

Tags: knockout.js

My two observables:

```
 this.name = ko.observable("");
 this.allItems = ko.observableArray(["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]);
```

My save function:

```
this.save = function () {

                tmp = {}
                tmp["name"] = ko.toJSON(this.funnelname);
                tmp["steps"] = ko.toJSON(this.allItems);
console.log(tmp);
}
```

The message at console with this code is :

```
{name: """", steps: "["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]"}
```

Should it be not like below before I stringify it and send it to server side code:

```
{name: "", steps: ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]}at
```

Would sincerely appreciate if someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that you change properties to string and then you create new object using 2 string properties. Instead you should create an object and then serialize it to string. Update your `save` function like this:

```
this.save = function () {
    tmp = {}
    tmp["name"] = this.funnelname;
    tmp["steps"] = this.allItems;
    console.log(ko.toJSON(tmp));
}
```